# Inner join between two tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am trying to create an inner join that will connect two MySQL tables together (patients and appointments table). I am displaying in a table all of the patients appointments which includes their patient id number. That patient id should display the patients (first name + last name) as fullname not their id number. If someone could help me create a query statement that would be appreciated. I am fairly new to MySQL, so a follow up explanation would be very helpful.

This is the structure of the patients table that I am wanting to join onto the appointments table:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

This is the structure of the appointments table:

[image]

This is the query statement I have tried to implement to try and display the fullname of the patient in the appointments table.

```
    function getAllCustomers(){
    $sql = "
SELECT a.appointmentid
     , a.doctorid
     , a.appointmentdate
     , a.appointmenttime
     , p1.Name
     , p2.Name
  FROM appointment
  JOIN patients p1
    ON patientid = p1.firstname
  JOIN patients p2
    ON patientid = p2.lastname;
";

    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/54kMn.png
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Please read "Getting started with SQL joins" https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: "patients appointments which includes their patient id number. That patient id should display the patients ... fullname not their id number."  What do you want? ID or not ID, that's the question. An ID displays an ID.

Comment: I am wanting to display the name of the patient that corresponds to the patient ID number

Comment: `SELECT wanted_field1, wanted_field2 FROM patients p INNER JOIN appointment a USING(patientid);`

Comment: the code is incomplete

Comment: @chris85 see my comment above yours I find is relevant and no idea if the OP knows what to do about solutions.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I might be overly optimistic that the OP just left out the execution.

Comment: @chris85 Not just that, but how they're calling that custom method and the API used to connect with. I voted to close as unclear because that's what I feel this question is.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Would I be able to add another inner join to my doctors table to do the same function?

Comment: @chris85 Yes, that is in reference to your answer. Also, the fullname that is being displayed is connected e.g MatthewRichardson. Is there a way I can separate the first and last name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't join the same table twice, also don't compare a string to an integer. I think something like:

```
SELECT a.appointmentid, 
       concat(p.firstname, ' ', p.lastname) as fullname_patient, 
       concat(d.firstname, ' ', d.lastname) as fullname_doctor
FROM appointment as a
INNER JOIN patients as p
ON a.patientid = p.patientid
inner join doctors as d
on a.doctorid = d.doctorid
```

would give you the information you want.

The [concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function concatenates the values given to it, use commas to separate each value.